# $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu):=((-1,1),\mathscr{B}((-1,1)),\lambda)$ is $f(x,y):=\dfrac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, proof-writing, borel-sets

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu):=((-1,1),\mathscr{B}((-1,1)),\lambda)$ be a measure space, where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$, and define the function by

$$
f(x,y):=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\hspace{0,7cm} \text{if} (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\
0\hspace{2,6cm}\text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

Show that $f$ is $\mathscr{F}\otimes\mathscr{F}/\mathbb{R}$-measurable.

We know that continuous maps between $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are measurable. Since $\mathscr{B}((-1,1))$ is also a topological space we could in case of $f$ being continuous also apply the aforementioned result. However $f$ isn't, so I'm not quite sure how to procced.

Edit: Wouldn't my idea actually work if we were to use $\infty$ instead of $0$ for the "else" case ?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Your inequality is false for $x=0$ and $y$ close to $0$. The function is not continuous.

Comment: Oh... right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n(x,y) =\frac {xy} {(x^{2}+y^2)^{2}}$ for $\|(x,y\| >\frac  1 n $ and $f_n(x,y) =n^{4}xy$ for $\|(x,y\| \leq \frac  1 n $. Then $f_n$ is continuous, hence Borel measurable. Further $f_n(x,y) \to f(x,y)$ for  all $(x,y)$. Since pointwise limits of measurable functions is measurable it follows that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: is there a reason for writing $n^4$ instead of just $n$ for example ?

Comment: @ChristianSinger If you have $n$ there then you must change $\|(x,y)\|>\frac 1  n$ to $\|(x,y)\|>\frac 1  {n^{1/4}}$,etc to make $f_n$ continuous.

Comment: This probably has something to do with the denominator of $f$ having exponent $4$ if $x=y$ but could you give me slightly more details

Comment: @ChristianSinger I am just trying to match the expressions for $f_n(x,y)$  in the two regions so that when $\|(x,y)\|$ is exactly $n$  I get the same value. So $n^{4}$ comes from the fact that $(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}=\|(x,y)\|^{4}=n^{4}$ when $\|(x,y)\|=\frac  1 n$.

Comment: Alright! Now I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function is almost everywhere continuous  and the measure of  $\{(0,0)\}$ is zero.

So the function is continuous a.e,so it is measurable.

Comment: There is a small caveat to address; as far as I understand, the sigma-algebra the OP referred to is the *Borel* one, which is not complete.

Comment: I agree with above comment. The question is not about Lebesgue measurability.

Comment: Okay: Managed to get confused about continuity, but my objection should still stand. Let $f$ be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $B$ be a non-Borel subset of the Cantor set $\mathfrak{C}$ (which I guess we only have given the continuum hypothesis, but I digress). Then $g:=f-1_B$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathfrak{C}$, since the Cantor Set is closed. Hence, $g$ is continuous a.e. But $g$ is not *Borel* measurable. You're obviously right that it's Lesbegue/Borel-measurable. I'm just saying some care should be taken and the OP clearly states that he's working with the Borel algebra